# How do I load pgm into figure environment?

Tags: graphics, floats, multimedia

With

```
\begin{figure}[H]
        \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{boat.pgm}
\end{figure}
```

I got `Unknown graphics extension: .pgm`

Is it possible to load a `pgm` file to `figure` environment?

Comment: You should search for graphic rules, then you could let it convert the image automatically when encountered (you'd need to have a converter installed though).

Comment: BTW, It has nothing to do with figure (which isn't really needed here anyway). The question is can \includegrphics handle .pgm format?